# Is it possible to change bluetooth profile on RPi4?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, pybluez

I have a camera connected to a RPi4 and I want to stream its feed via bluetooth.
BLE max speed is 2 Mbps, which is a little too slow.
I'd like to switch to bluetooth classic, to reach 24 Mbps. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is example code for how to switch profiles in BlueZ at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-profile

I am assuming you are interested in the VDP profile which is documented at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/)

However, I don't see VDP as one of the supported profiles supported by BlueZ which are documented at http://www.bluez.org/profiles/

This is about the only reference I can find to it: http://www.bluez.org/gsoc-video-distribution-profilevdp/