# Send Sensor Data & Stream Video Over Bluetooth (Raspberry Pi to PC)

Tags: python, video, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I would like to send sensor data (string) and live video from the Raspberry Pi camera over Bluetooth. I would like to do this with python. I would like to display the video on the PC in a tkinter window. Any ideas??

Raspberry Pi: Pi 3 
PC: Windows 10 with Python 3.8.3 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video might be a bit tricky. More details at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64062680/7721752

Bluetooth on Windows with Python is not that well supported. However, with Python 3.9 there is support for Serial Port Profile (SPP). There is details of how to create the client at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62815818/7721752

To create the Server on the Raspberry Pi (RPi) I would use the Bluedot library:
https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothserver
(Bluedot only works on RPi)

Developing both ends of a Bluetooth link at the same time is tricky if you are new to creating Bluetooth. My suggestion would be to create the Server on the RPi first and use an app like [Serial Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal) on your phone to test it. Once that is working start on developing the client.